# Wordpress: get_user_meta - Two Variables in one Field

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I do have a quick question because I have no idea how to solve that. I get the following user meta data from my database with the following code:

```
<?php
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $birthday_day = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'geburtstag', true );
        $emailvalue = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'user_email', true );
        $firstNamevalue = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'first_name', true );
        $lastNamevalue = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'last_name', true );
?>
```

Now I would like to post those values with an array into another table at my database. Therefore I have the following code:

```
<?php
        $wpdb->insert($paymentTable,
      array(
        'event_id'=> $id,
        'date_id'=> $dateid,
        'ticket_id'=> $ticket,
        'coupon'=> $coupon,
        'date_paid'=> $payment_date,
        'type'=> $bookingType,
        'name'=> $firstNamevalue,
        'email'=> $emailvalue,
        'birthday'=> date('Y-m-d', strtotime($birthday_day)),
        'phone'=> $phone,
        'address'=> $address,
        'txn_id'=> 'N.A',
        'amount'=> $amount,
        'quantity'=> $quantity,
        'status'=> $status,
        'extras'=> $formStuff)
    );
?>
```

Everything is working fine and everything is saved inside my database in the correct table. The only problem I have now is, that in my field 'name' only the first name of my user is written!

How can I achieve it that $firstNamevalue and $lastNamevalue are written inside my field 'name' so that there is: John Doe instead of only John as it is right now. Can someone tell me how I can do that with my array?

I really appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only problem I have now is, that in my field `'name'` only the first name of my user is written!

That's because you've set `'name'=> $firstNamevalue,`...

Instead, concatenate the first and last names to make a full name:

```
'name'=> $firstNamevalue . ' ' . $lastNamevalue,
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank your for your fast response!